# Ubuntu server 22.04 port forwarding issue

Tags: networking, server, port-forwarding, nextcloud, mediaserver

I am trying to use an old Shuttle xPC as a home server. I've installed Ubuntu Server 22.04, Cockpit (with Navigator and File share), AdGuard Home, qBittoreent, Jellyfin and Nextcloud. On my home network everything is working fine, but I am unable to access anything from outside. The Linux machine is set with a static IP address - 192.168.1.101. In my router (Huawei HG630 v2) I set up port forwarding as follow:
ext. port 884 - 192.168.1.101:9090 (Cockpit)
ext. port 885 - 192.168.1.101:8080 (qBittoreent)
ext. port 886 - 192.168.1.101:8096 (Jellyfin)
ext. port 887 - 192.168.1.101:8098 (AdGuard Home)
ext. port 888 - 192.168.1.101:8888 (Nextcloud)

Ext. ports 880-883 are forwarded to two NAS devices, which are working perfectly and are fully accessable from internet.

Actually, forwarding for Nextcloud was set some time ago, when I was using the same machine as a cloud storage and 'home-only' media server and then it was working and accessable?! Now I've just enable that rule, but it is not working anymore.
For Nextcloud I used the exact same installation method and settings as before. Can post the whole setting up procedure if needed.